# Selenium WebDriver - Start after load the page completely

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to get some elements from a web page. like Tile. JS load first and then HTML elements are loaded.
I want to wait until the page load completely with our doms.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(sourcelink);
var title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3"));
```

with the above codes, the page was loaded but it never run the last line.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(sourcelink);
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//h1")));
var title = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3"));
```

I wrote another code. we will wait for `h1` tag. after that it seems all elements loaded.
I got this error

```
unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
```

Please help me how can I tell the selenium run last line, after all, elements loaded completely.

Comment: have you tried `presenceOfElementLocatedBy` or  `visibilityOfElementLocatedBy` ​?

Comment: @Akzy yes. I got this `error unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response` after this line  `new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//h1")));`